# ASP.NET Core MVC IFormFile returns null in Post request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to build an app to store car parts.
I created the app with ASP.NET Core MVC following this tutorial: https://www.codaffection.com/asp-net-core-article/asp-net-core-mvc-image-upload-and-retrieve/

My Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace UploadTest.Models
{
    public class CarPart
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Part Number")]
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Image Name")]
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Upload File")]
        public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I added a Scaffolded Item and Created a Controller including the Views etc.
The Controller for `Create` (POST):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,Amount,PartNumber,ImageName")] CarPart carPart)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(carPart.ImageFile.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(carPart.ImageFile.FileName);
        carPart.ImageName = fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff")+extension;
        string path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/Image/", fileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await carPart.ImageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
        //Insert record
        _context.Add(carPart);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(carPart);
}
```

The view for `Create`:

```
@model UploadTest.Models.CarPart

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>CarPart</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PartNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PartNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PartNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ImageFile" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ImageFile" type="file"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="ImageFile" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

The problem is now that when the `Create` method is called the value for the `ImageFile` is `null`.

See image: [ScreenShot of the DebugSession](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzrk8.png)

I tried to search several hints here and at other places but can't find why the image file is not coming into the controller.

Thanks

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0 . Uploading files to wwwroot is very insecure

Comment: Perhaps because you are not using ImageFile in your bind attribute? Furthermore, you might want to use a form and formdata if you are currently using the body to post the data. Look into using iformfile with a form

Comment: Hey thanks. You were right. It was the bind attribute -.-
And yeah I know about the security risks. But the upload function is going to be only accessible to a trusted personell.

Answer (score 0):

As "S. ten Brinke" posted in the comments. I forgot to add the ImageFile in the bind attribute.
Once added everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am just postin this answer because my comment was the answer! If you could accept this answer as the correct one I would get some SO points :)

Your problem is you did not include it in the Bind attribute